# Is frame drag the magnetic part of gravity?

Tags: general-relativity, frame-dragging

Like moving charged mass creates an magnetic field, does moving mass also creates a magnetic field associated with moving (accelerated) mass? And if so, why does the mass have to accelerate, while in the case of the three basic forces (although I doubt the fundamental status of the weak force) the objects just have to move without acceleration?

Comment: You are taking the (unfortunate) name "gravitomagnetism" a little to literally.

Answer (score 3):

The precise tensors needed to describe the fields and waves are different in electromagnetism and gravity. The basic potential in electromagnetism is $A_\mu$, a vector in the case of electromagnetism, but $h_{\mu\nu}$, a symmetric tensor in gravity. However, most of the basic qualitative facts are the same.

The *are* some fields in both cases, like the magnetic field $F_{ij}$ and the components $h_{0j}$ in the gravitational field, that *are* nonzero whenever an object (charge in electromagnetism, mass in gravity) moves, even if it moves at a constant speed. However, there's no completely antisymmetric tensor in gravity that would be similar to $F_{ij}$ in electromagnetism, the magnetic field. In the case of magnetism, we often use the cross product or the "epsilon symbol". Nothing like that is done with the gravitational fields – this epsilon-based "gravimagnetism" doesn't exist.

On the other hand, in both cases, waves (gravitational or electromagnetic waves) carrying away energy are only created when the source (mass or charge) accelerates.

These waves are emitted, propagate by the speed of light, and may be derived by analogous mathematics. There are some differences. For example, the leading emission comes from an oscillating *electric dipole* in electromagnetism. Because of the extra index and the extra conservation law in gravity (the law that the center-of-mass moves along a straight line, something that isn't true for the center-of-charge, a charge-weighted average position), the basic gravitational wave radiation comes from an oscillating *quadrupole*, not a dipole (the latter is constant by the conservation law).

Both waves/particles (photons, gravitons) have 2 physical transverse polarizations in our 3+1-dimensional spacetime, but this agreement is largely a coincidence (it doesn't hold in spacetimes of other dimensions, for example) and the two polarizations look different in detail (although one may still call them linear or circular polarizations) and the photons' can't be identified with the gravitons' "exactly".

Comment: Why do photons (in the transverse, non covariant gauge) and gravitons don´t have two tranverse polarization states in a non-three-dimensional space (why is it an accident of three dimensional space that they have each two transverse polarization states)? Can this be answered in an intuïtive way, or does one háve to use math?

Comment: It's simple, @descheleschilder - In $D$ spacetime dimension, the vector field always has $D-2$ components simply because the timelike $A_0$ and the longitudinal $A_\mu\sim k_\mu$ components are forbidden. Similarly, the gravitaton has $(D-2)(D-1)/2 - 1$ polarizations, a traceless (therefore minus one) symmetric tensor $h_{ij}$ in the $(D-2)$-dimensional transverse space. I don't know whether it's intuitive. If you want to compare the number of components, you should learn at least some basic numbers such as two, three, etc. ;-)

Comment: Motl Haha! I think I once upon a time I learned these things called numbers. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Frame dragging refers to the "motion of space" as represented in some frame. A Schwarzschild metric in a space plus time format can be seen as moving particles according to frame dragging. The following animation file illustrates this

[image]

The expansion of space in cosmology is also a form of frame dragging.

The term frame dragging is most often referred to with the Kerr metric. A rotating black hole drags points of space around it, a bit like a vortex, so that at the static limit it is not possible to resist this motion by accelerating in a counter rotating direction.

In some sense frame dragging is the dynamics of space. This sort of diagram is illustrative, but it is better to show the direction of light cones. If light cones at different regions of spacetime have different directions their null rays point there is then gravity or what can be called frame dragging.

Comment: But how is this dynamics of space generated?

Comment: In the animation, is it space falling to the singularity?